# How to suppress Flash migration warnings (1090)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, suppress-warnings, mxmlc

In Flash Professional CS4, I get "migration issue" warnings when I use mouse/keyboard input handler names such as onMouseDown, onKeyUp, etc., even though I have added event listeners for them. These names are perfectly legal for functions, but since these were automatically fired in ActionScript 2.0, we are now (albeit sensibly) warned that their use is no longer automatic in AS3.

I understand the purpose of the warnings, but they aren't useful for me. I want to suppress these warnings, but *without* suppressing any other warnings, which I generally *do* find useful.

E.g., when I use code like this:

```
/** @constructor */
public function MyClass() {
  addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
}

protected function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
```

I get an annoying warning like this:

`Warning: 1090: Migration issue: The onMouseDown event handler is not triggered automatically by Flash Player at run time in ActionScript 3.0.  You must first register this handler for the event using addEventListener ( 'mouseDown', callback_handler).`

There are flex compiler (mxmlc) flags (and a Flash Pro setting) which can suppress actionscript warnings, or *all* warnings, but I don't want that. That's too general.

Ideally I could **suppress a specific error/warning number** (Warning #1090).

**Edit**: I've found more "advanced" compiler flags with `mxmlc -help advanced`, which look promising. Specifically, the following seem like likely candidates:
`warn-deprecated-event-handler-error`
`warn-deprecated-function-error`
`warn-deprecated-property-error`

How do I get Flash to use these?

**Edit 2**: I found a flex-info.xml style document in the Flash User Data dir.
`[userdatafolder]/Adobe/Flash CS4/en/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/FlexInfo.xml`
However, this file contains a disappointing comment: `<!-- Flash does not support most flex-config options. -->`, and doesn't seem to respond to my directives even after restarting flash.
This is getting sad.

**Edit 3**: Found an issue "[Erroneous, annoying "Migration issue" warnings](https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-13911)" on Adobe bug tracker. A fix is confirmed for the Flex SDK, but no mention of Flash...

Comment: Flash Builder (CS4), not Flex, sorry. Too easy otherwise!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can if you edit **EnabledWarnings.xml** in $Flash/$LOCALE/Configuration/Actionscript 3.0/EnabledWarnings.xml, where $Flash is the path to Flash inside your Applications/Program Files folder and $LOCALE is your language.

e.g.

`/Applications/Adobe Flash CS4/en/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/EnabledWarnings.xml`

You will need to edit line 29, setting the **enabled** attribute to **false** for **warning** with id **1090**:

```
<warning id="1090" enabled="false"  label="kWarning_DepricatedEventHandlerError">EventHandler was not added as a listener.</warning>
```

---

*Quick sidenote:*

"Flash Builder (CS4)" is a confusing term. After Flex Builder 3, Flex Builder got renamed to Flash Builder, there is no Flash Builder CS4. The regular Flash IDE is known as Flash Professional/Flash Professional CS4, this was to avoid confusion between products with similar names: Flash Catalyst, Flash Builder(was Flex Builder), Flash Professional. Obviously it doesn't always work that great :)

Comment: Man. First accurate answer so far, will check it out.

Comment: Excellent. This is exactly the answer I was looking for. Thank you so much, George, you're a saint. No pun intented.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for clearing up that stuff about Flash Builder/Flash Professional.

Comment: No worries, glad that helps. There only a few warnings that are important, most of them are related to migration issues.

Answer (score 3):

What about changing the name of the function being called from onMouseDown to handlerOnMouseDown. Would it solve the issue?

Are you using Flex Builder? 
If so, go to Project -> Properties -> Flex Compiler. There you can add arguments to the compiler.

Comment: Yes, that would stop the warnings. But it wouldn't soothe my aching heart. I like "onMouseDown" more than "onMouseDownHandler" or "onMouseDown2", etc...

Comment: And no, using Flash Builder (CS4).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you overriding that? It never existed in the first place. The error message is actually telling you something useful. Don't suppress it.

If you want to create an event handler called onMouseDown, try something like

```
private function onMouseDown(e:MouseEvent) : void {
  // statements
}
```

Comment: Ah crap, thank you for pointing that out. The override keyword is a typo - I copied the line from a subclass. :/

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous post; the message is trying to tell you that you need to register that event handler. Just adding a method called onMouseDown() won't do it. What you need to do is to add something like

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
```

in either your constructor or maybe in the parent component.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps I need to make it clear that I have added the event listener, and I still get the warning... thanks for comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out these warnings using Flash Builder's problems filtering capability:

- open problems view
- on the right click on the small triangle that opens a drop-down menu
- select *Configure Contents...*
- on the left side, create a new configuration, name it as you wish
- on the right side adjust its settings:

  - *Scope:* On any element in the same project (or anything you want)
  - ***Description:*** choose *doesn't contain* and type in *Migration issue* (this will filter out warnings with migration issue in the description)
  - choose at least Flex problems

You can combine predefined and custom configurations by selecting more then one on the left side.